# Retail webApi services AX7

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax7

We are trying to access AX7 data via retail services using webAPi such as

https://AX---.cloud.dynamics.com/commerce/customer

so that we can directly use the data for our mobile App.

I am not good at retailsdk part. Can anyone provide the list of standard services with required parameters to pass under URL.

Or, if there is anything else required to expose the standard services as webAPI.

Also, what kind of authentication is required for this and how to provide that under the URL itself?

Answer (score 1):

The Commerce APIs are exposed using the [OData protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh237663.aspx), there are several OData libraries for different programming languages out there that you can use to consume the endpoint, [this in one example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app).

The endpoint uses [OpenID protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) for authentication, so you can register any OpenID service to provide you authentication. Out of the box, you can use the OpenID implementation that ships with the Commerce API itself.

However, it's easier than that. The Retail SDK ships with a .NET library called RetailProxy that has everything done for you to consume that endpoint. So if you are using .NET or can integrate with it, that's probably the easiest and most reliable way to consume the Commerce APIs.

I would also suggest this developer [documentation about the RetailSDK](https://ax.help.dynamics.com/en/wiki/microsoft-dynamics-ax-retail-for-it-pros-and-developers/) to get you started.